# Combine column from multiple rows into single row with id

Tags: sql-server

I have on table which store enter and exit of people in multi rows like:

EorL 1 = enter

EorL 2 = exit or leave

```
id   |  date_    |time    |EorL|
1    |  150201   | 09:14  | 1  |
2    |  150201   | 09:14  | 1  |
3    |  150201   | 09:15  | 1  |
1    |  150201   | 16:07  | 2  |
2    |  150201   | 16:07  | 2  |
3    |  150201   | 17:15  | 2  |
```

how can combine and get:

```
id    |   date_     |enter     |leave
1     |  150201     |09:14     |16:07
2     |  150201     |09:14     |16:07
3     |  150201     |09:15     |17:15
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a simple self join:

```
SELECT 
    enter.id,
    enter.date_ 
    enter.time AS enter_time
    leave.time AS leave_time
FROM 
    tablename AS enter
  JOIN
    tablename AS leave
  ON  enter.id = leave.id
  AND enter.date_ = leave.date_
  AND leave.EorL = 2 
WHERE
    enter.EorL = 1 ;
```

The query assumes there are (max) 2 rows for any `id` and `date_`.

If there are cases where people have entered without leaving, use `LEFT` join instead. If there are people who have left without entering, use `RIGHT` join. If there might be both cases, use `FULL` join. For `RIGHT` and `FULL`, you'll have to adjust the `SELECT` list, using `leave.id, leave.date_` and `COALESCE(enter.id, leave.id), COALESCE(enter.date_, leave.date_)`.